# TYPO3 foreign_table_where not works properly

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 version 7.6.18.

```
'images' => [
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:fefiles/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:images',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'inline',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_fefiles_domain_model_photo',
        'foreign_field' => 'album',
        'foreign_table_where' => 'AND tx_fefiles_domain_model_photo.allow = 1',
        'maxitems' => '5000'
    ],
],
```

This is configuration in TCA for someone field. 
in table tx_fefiles_domain_model_photo I have 4 rows which id = album,
but allow = 1 only two. But I get all four rows. My condition tx_fefiles_domain_model_photo.allow = 1 does't works. I tried different variants, cleared cache. Really I need your help, I must make it works, help me please (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
'foreign_match_fields' => [
    'allow' => 1
]
```

instead of `foreign_table_where`.
For examples look into documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/

Comment: Thomas, great danker!